# Size of the shortest path between two nodes in Jtree

Tags: java, jtree

I have a Jtree created using Java. Now I want to find a size of the shortest path between two nodes in Jtree.

Example:

[image]

```
b to c ----size of the shortest path=2
d to f-----size of the shortest path=2
d to g-----size of the shortest path=3
```

I used following code.I used `SharedAncestor` for that.

```
public int nodeDistance(String s1, String s2) {

            JavaTreeFinal obt1 = new JavaTreeFinal();
            DefaultMutableTreeNode term1 = obt1.nodeReg.get((String) s1);
            DefaultMutableTreeNode term2 = obt1.nodeReg.get((String) s2);

            TreeNode sharedAncestor = term1.getSharedAncestor(term2);
            int levelAns = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) sharedAncestor).getLevel();
            int levelTerm1 = term1.getLevel();
            int levelTerm2 = term2.getLevel();
            int level1 = levelTerm1-levelAns;
            int level2 = levelTerm1-levelAns;
            int shortPath = level1+level2;

            return shortPath;           
        }
```

using `SharedAncestor` can I do it correctly? 
Because if there more SharedAncestors it will give wrong?
And this code only give one SharedAncestors. So is it nearest SharedAncestors ?
Or any other simple and correct way to find it?

How can I find it using Java?

Comment: Do you need the length of that path (which you already calculate) or the path itself? Besides that your code seems to be correct since `getSharedAncestor(node)` as per its JavaDoc `Returns the nearest common ancestor to this node and aNode`.

Comment: I want to take length of the path. (I put simple example)

Comment: I am confusing about, if there more SharedAncestors it will give wrong result? And this code only give one SharedAncestors. So is it nearest SharedAncestor ?

Comment: Yes, as the JavaDoc states: "Returns the _nearest_ common ancestor to this node and aNode. Returns null, if no such ancestor exists."

Comment: Ok.So, I think my code will give correct result. Thank you very much for your reply.